# MvxSpinner Binding Issue on Xamarin.Android MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

Using Xamarin.Android with MVVMCross. When Select the value from MVXSpinner  that Not Binding to `SelectedYear` Property in the Model. When Load the page debugger comes in to `SelectedYear` Property, But When I select the value from spinner it want comes into `SelectedYear`. I haven't get any errors. Please Any one Advice me where I am wrong.

Found Binding Issue on Output Window

MvxBind:Warning:228.30 Failed to create target binding for binding SelectedItem for SelectedYear
[0:] MvxBind:Warning:228.30 Failed to create target binding for binding SelectedItem for SelectedYear
11-09 11:50:03.756 I/mono-stdout(32419): MvxBind:Warning:228.30 Failed to create target binding for binding SelectedItem for SelectedYear

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Retread.Collection.UI.DroidPhone.DotYear"
            style="@style/LabelTextView" />
        <MvxSpinner
            android:id="@+id/txtYear"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overlapAnchor="false"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@drawable/year_spinner"
            local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@drawable/year_spinnerdropdown"
            android:hint="@string/Retread.Collection.UI.DroidPhone.Year"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Year;SelectedItem SelectedYear"
            style="@style/AppSpinnerStyle" />
```

Year_spinner.xml File below.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        local:MvxBind="Text DisplayYear"/>
```

Year_spinnerdropdown.xml file Below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    local:MvxBind="Text DisplayYear" />
```

In View Model I have Following Properties. And In the Year Model I have a Property `DisplayYear`.

```
 private List<YearModel> _Year;
            public List<YearModel> Year
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Year;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Year = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Year);
                }
            }

       public YearModel SelectedYear
        {
            get
            {
                return Model.SelectedYear;
            }
            set
            {
                Model.SelectedYear = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedYear);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are not making yourself clear what is wrong here. What is the expected result? What do you see? Why is it wrong?

Comment: The expected result is when I post the form I need the binding value(selected Value) in SelectedYear Property. But I haven't get any values(null) in SelectedYear Property. What I See is When I Select a value from Dropdown No event triggered into ViewModel to SelectedYear Property. I haven't know where I let mistake.

Comment: Show us your YearModel code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if I post something that works for me it can point you in the right direction.

Spinner:

```
<Mvx.MvxSpinner
    style="@style/spinner"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinner"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Position; SelectedItem SelectedPosition"
    android:id="@+id/positionSpinner" />
```

MvxItemTemplate:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Spinner.MyPlayers"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dummy_title"
    local:MvxBind="Text Caption" />
```

ViewModel:

```
protected int SelectedPositionId
{
    get { return SelectedPosition == null ? 1 : SelectedPosition.Index; }
}

protected SpinnerItem _selectedPosition;
public virtual SpinnerItem SelectedPosition
{
    get { return _selectedPosition; }
    set 
    { 
        if (_selectedPosition != value)
        {
            _selectedPosition = value;

            SettingsPreferences.SelectedPosition = SelectedPositionId;

            RebuildLists(true);

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedPosition);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => DisplayCleanSheets);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => FilteredPlayers);
        }
    }
}

List<SpinnerItem> _position;
public List<SpinnerItem> Position
{
    get 
    { 
        if (_position != null)
            return _position; 

        _position = new List<SpinnerItem>();

        var values = (int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(PositionEnumeration));

        foreach (var val in values.Where(p => p > 0))
            _position.Add(new SpinnerItem(val, SharedTextSource.GetText(Enum.GetName(typeof(PositionEnumeration), val))));

        return _position;
    }
}
```

SpinnerItem:

```
public class SpinnerItem
{
    public SpinnerItem(int index, string caption, int primaryKeyId = 0, string tag = "")
    {
        Index = index;
        Caption = caption;
        PrimaryKeyId = primaryKeyId;
        Tag = tag;
    }

    public int Index { get; private set; }

    public string Caption { get; private set; }

    public string Tag { get; private set; }

    public int PrimaryKeyId { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Caption;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var rhs = obj as SpinnerItem;

        if (rhs == null)
            return false;

        return rhs.Caption == Caption;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Caption == null ? 0 : Caption.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer here
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/issues/80

> You'll need to call MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories from
>   your Setup.cs. Maybe there's a way we can automate that via the plugin
>   architecture?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11254333)

Comment: @maazza doesn't it contain the answer already? 

"You'll need to call MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories from your Setup.cs"